# GetEnumerator Error with Custom Type

Tags: c#, oop, ienumerable

I have the following Class...

```
class gridRecord
{
    //Constructor
    public gridRecord()
    {
        Quantity = new quantityField();
        Title = new titleField();
        Pages = new pagesField();
    }
    private quantityField quantity;
    private titleField title;
    private pagesField pages;



    internal quantityField Quantity
    {
        get { return quantity; }
        set { quantity = value; }
    }

    internal titleField Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    internal pagesField Pages
    {
        get { return pages; }
        set { pages = value; }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to get the name of each field as a string so I can later create a datable with out having to specify each column.

```
List<gridRecord> lgr = new List<gridRecord>();
lgr = populatedList();

foreach(gridField gf in lgr[0])
    MessageBox.Show(gf.ToString());
```

But I get this error:

> Error 1   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'XML__Console.gridRecord' because 'XML__Console.gridRecord' does not
>   contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I assume I need to inherit form and interface or something but not sure how or which one.

Grid Field Added...

```
class gridField : Validateit
{
    public gridField()
    {
        Value = "---";
        isValid = false;
        message = "";
    }
    private string value;
    protected bool isValid;
    private string message;

    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return isValid; }
        set { isValid = value; }
    }
    public string Message
    {
        get { return message; }
        set { message = value; }
    }
    public override void Validate()
    {

    }
}
```

quantityField added below the other fields are much the same

```
class quantityField : gridField
    {

        public void validate()
        {            
            if (isQuantityValid(Value) == false) { Value = "Invalid";}           
        }

        public static bool isQuantityValid(string quantity)
        {

            if (quantity.Length > 3)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: IEnumerable -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: can you give more details  ?

Comment: As an aside C# allows your properties to be like this  internal quantityField Quantity{get;set;}

Comment: where is `gridField` defined??

Comment: @Ric it is not defined

Comment: `foreach(gridField gf in lgr[0])`  - how do you expect `foreach` to iterate through *single* item `lgr[0]` ?

Comment: @ric I assume its the base class for all the fields

Comment: I'm guessing quantityField, titleField and pagesField all inherit from gridField...

Comment: I believe the OP wants to iterate through the properties of the `gridRecord` class, so `gridField` is wishful thinking.

Comment: I have been reading about IEnumerable but cant work out how to use it exactly.

Comment: this question is a bit unclear to about what is being asked and what is actually needed.

Comment: OP: Would you mind editing the question to remove the `List<gridRecord>`? It seems to be causing confusion and the point would be made just as well by declaring a `gridRecord` on its own? I'm happy to edit the code for you but don't want to change the code without your confirmation that you are happy with that and that it is indeed a correct edit. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i understood, you want to get the name of the properties from the `gridRecord` class (from your example: "Quantity", "Title", "Pages")?

For that, you need to use Reflection:

```
var properties = typeof(gridRecord).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in properties) {
    MessageBox.Show(propInfo.Name);
}
```

Comment: Its also worth noting that attributes could be used if you want the display name not to be the same as the property name.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to iterate over one element of the collection.

```
foreach(gridField gf in lgr[0])
{
    MessageBox.Show(gf.ToString());
}
```

If your goal is to retrieve the name of each property within the class, then do this.

```
PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(gridRecord).GetProperties();
foreach(PropertyInfo prop in props) 
{
    object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
    foreach(object attr in attrs) 
    {
        AuthorAttribute authAttr = attr as AuthorAttribute;
        if (authAttr != null) 
        {
            string propName = prop.Name;
            string auth = authAttr.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the original post "I want to be able to get the name of each field as a string". The OP does want to loop through the fields in the `gridRecord`.

Comment: No -- I think hes trying to iterate through the fields in the class. Which will need a enumerator

Comment: Yes basicly, I want to be able to add a new field say "Price" by adding a new class for that field and adding the field to Grid_Record. so eventually my datagridview will adapt to include the fields that are added.

Comment: Do I was trying to get the field names from the first element

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get name of each field you should use [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx).
[PropertyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) class should be helpful