# Make my Type work like a list

Tags: c#, .net, oop, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have created a list of my own type... (Classes for custom types at bottom of page)

```
List<gridRecord> lgr = new List<gridRecord>();
lgr = populatedList();
```

I validate each field in the List with the code bellow... (This works fine!)

```
foreach (gridRecord gr in lgr)
{
    gr.Quantity.validate();
    gr.Title.validate();
    gr.Pages.validate();
    dt.Rows.Add(gr.Title.Value.ToString(), gr.Quantity.Value.ToString(), gr.Pages.Value.ToString());
}
```

However I will be adding new gridFields to the gridRecord Class, and do not want to change the code that is validating.

so...I would like to be able to do something like this...

```
foreach (gridField gf in lgr)
{ 
    gf.Validate();
}
```

grid Record Class...

```
class gridRecord : Validateit
{
    //Constructor
    public gridRecord()
    {
        Quantity = new quantityField();
        Title = new titleField();
        Pages = new pagesField();
    }
    private quantityField quantity;
    private titleField title;
    private pagesField pages;



    public quantityField Quantity
    {
        get { return quantity; }
        set { quantity = value; }
    }

    public titleField Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    public pagesField Pages
    {
        get { return pages; }
        set { pages = value; }
    }

    public override void Validate()
    {

    }
}
```

gridField Class...

```
class gridField : Validateit
{
    public gridField()
    {
        Value = "---";
        isValid = false;
        message = "";
    }

    private string value;
    protected bool isValid;
    private string message;


    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return isValid; }
        set { isValid = value; }
    }
    public string Message
    {
        get { return message; }
        set { message = value; }
    }

    public override void Validate()
    {

    }
}
```

do I need to use `IEnumerable` if so how?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is *really* hard to read because it's all badly formatted. In any case - is `Validateit` an interface or base class? Does it define the `Validate` method?

Comment: with reflection its possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class

Comment: I fixed the class header that was not formatted right.

Comment: is this similar to your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149703/getenumerator-error-with-custom-type

Comment: @Jamiec did not want to include to much code the validate method works fine, did not see how it was relevant.

Comment: Yes It is similar but although I know how to get the properties as strings this requires taking that properties then executing a method from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want code like this:

```
foreach (gridRecord gr in lgr)
{ 
    gr.Validate();
}
```

It is a simple case of implementing what you need within that `Validate` method of `gridRecord` (BTW: That class should be named `GridRecord` - classes should start with an upper case character according to C# naming convention)

```
class gridRecord : Validateit
{
    //.. snip
   public override void Validate()
   {
        this.Quantity.Validate();
        this.Title.Validate();
        this.Pages.Validate();
   }
}
```

If, however, you want to *enumerate all the fields* you can make each `gridRecord` implement `IEnumerable<gridField>` like this:

```
class gridRecord : Validateit, IEnumerable<gridField>
{
    //.. snip
   public IEnumerator<gridField> GetEnumerator()
   {
        yield return Quantity;
        yield return Title;
        yield return Pages;
   }

   public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
   {
       return GetEnumerator(); // generic version
   }
}
```

Then you can have code like this:

```
foreach (gridRecord gr in lgr) // enumerate each record
{ 
    foreach(gridField gf in gr) // enumerate each field within each record
    {
       gf.Validate();
    }
}
```